# How does Cache leverage locality?

Tags: database, caching

Cache has locality (temporal locality, spatial locality)
But I don't know how to use it
Please see if what I am saying is correct.

When caching data A, other nearby data is also cached.
So you can take advantage of spatial locality. (When you request data called B next to A, it will already be loaded into memory by A request)

You can also take advantage of temporal locality. Because recently referenced data goes into the cache, It is likely to be referenced frequently. So it can be seen that time locality is utilized.

Comment: It's hard to know what you're trying to do because you didn't really state your goal or what technology you're using, but general databases handle caching for you transparently and it's not something you have to activity 'use'. It just happens.